# Splitting a symbol, in the same manner as one would split a string

Tags: ruby, split, symbols

Is it possible to split a symbol without first converting it to a string? For example, I've tried

```
:split_this.split("_")
```

and it only returns an error. I've looked through the [Symbol class reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html), but all the example use `to_s` to convert it to a string.

I know I can convert it to a string, split it, and convert the two substrings to symbols, but that just seems a bit cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: what is your expected out?

Comment: `:split_this.to_s.split("_").map(&:intern)` doesn't seem that cumbersome to me. Many symbol methods work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Ruby 1.9 some string's features are added to the `Symbol` class but not this much.The best you can do, I think is:

```
:symbol_with_underscores.to_s.split('_').map(&:to_sym)
```

You could turn this into a `Symbol` method:

```
class Symbol
  def split(separator)
    to_s.split(separator).map(&:to_sym)
  end
end

:symbol_with_underscores.split('_')
# => [:symbol, :with, :underscores]
```

Answer (score 3):

Think about symbols as numbers. Because symbols are internally stored as [int numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879142/3315). Therefore they don't have string related methods.

Comment: Actually symbols are often manipulated as strings in Ruby, think of ActiveRecord's dynamic finders for example. The core library itself defines some string methods for symbols i.e. `downcase`, `capitalize`.

Comment: @toro2k Each subsequent **Rails** version has less of the magic. Moreover, overuse of string to symbol conversions led to [CVE-2013-1854 Symbol DoS vulnerability in Active Record](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-security-ann/o0Dsdk2WrQ0)