# Scala: Create enumeration object from a set

Tags: scala, reflection, enumeration

I would like to know whether there is any way to create an enumeration class from a set (e.g., a set of strings).

Below is a simple attempt:

```
val s = Set("v1", "v2", "v3")

object sEnum extends Enumeration {
  for (v <- s) {
    val v = Value
  }
}

for (v <- sEnum.values) {
  println(v)
}
```

The enumeration object seems to compile, but it's values are wonky: the print loop shows that the values inside sEnum look like this:

> <Invalid enum: no field for #0>

Thus, the problem seems to be at the value declaration

```
val v = Value
```

Is there some way that I can replace the variable v by its contents at run time (using reflection I assume)?

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: Look at the example at the bottom.*

The values in your enum don't have string names (although they have unique numeric IDs). There are two ways how an enum value can get a string name:

1. You pass it explicitly when calling `Value`, e.g. `Value("v1")`
2. If you create a `val` field in the class, Scala infers the value from the field name, e.g. in `val v1 = Value`. This is done internally via reflection, by examining all 0-args methods which return a conforming type.

The second case doesn't apply to your example: `val v = Value` doesn't create a *method* on the class, `v` is just a local variable inside the loop (hiding the iteration variable `v`). So you need to take the first approach:

```
val s = Set("v1", "v2", "v3")
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  s.foreach(Value(_))
}
MyEnum.values.foreach(println) // prints v1 v2 v3
```

Now, this doesn't allow you to access your enum values easily, `MyEnum.v1` won't work. There is no way how to add methods/fields dynamically to a class based on a set of string values. At least not without some magic bytecode manipulation where you probably don't want to venture.

Instead, you can define a custom method for retrieving the values. Here's an example using [Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/780287/2032064), so that you don't need to use the inefficient `MyEnum.withName()` method:

```
val s = Set("v1", "v2", "v3")

object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value
  s.foreach(Value(_))

  private val constants = s.map(v => Symbol(v) -> withName(v)).toMap
  def apply(c: Symbol): MyEnum = constants(c)
}

MyEnum.values.foreach(println) // prints v1 v2 v3
println(MyEnum('v1)) // prints v1
```