# How does `as 'value` work in Spark in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use Spark in Scala, I found three ways to do same thing (?)

```scala
.select(to_avro(struct("*"), toAvroConfig).alias("value"))
.select(to_avro(struct("*"), toAvroConfig).as("value"))
.select(to_avro(struct("*"), toAvroConfig) as 'value)
```

I found documents about first two:

`alias` [doc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f24a7f54d9abd0cb7ad27f91d18526f143f6ba1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L1089-L1100):

```
  def alias(alias: String): Column = name(alias)

  /**
   * Gives the column an alias.
   * {{{
   *   // Renames colA to colB in select output.
   *   df.select($"colA".as("colB"))
   * }}}
   *
   * If the current column has metadata associated with it, this metadata will be propagated
   * to the new column. If this not desired, use the API `as(alias: String, metadata: Metadata)`
   * with explicit metadata.
   *
   * @group expr_ops
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
```

`as` [doc](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f24a7f54d9abd0cb7ad27f91d18526f143f6ba1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L1089-L1100):

```
  def as(alias: String): Column = name(alias)

  /**
   * (Scala-specific) Assigns the given aliases to the results of a table generating function.
   * {{{
   *   // Renames colA to colB in select output.
   *   df.select(explode($"myMap").as("key" :: "value" :: Nil))
   * }}}
   *
   * @group expr_ops
   * @since 1.4.0
   */
```

For last one `as 'value`, I found it [here](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/documentation/vanilla-avro-documentation.md). Initially I thought it is a typo, but it is actually valid. How does it work?  Is there a document about it?

Are all three same? Thanks!

Comment: `'value` is deprecated syntax for a `Symbol` and either there is an overload or some implicit conversion from `Symbol` to `String`, or maybe the compiler treats the subtypes since symbols are just constant strings. - anyways, that thing is not used anymore in modern **Scala** _(although **Spark** is far from that anyways)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scaladoc` that correspond to the `method`, is the one that is above. So, the doc for `def alias(alias: String): Column = name(alias)` is [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f24a7f54d9abd0cb7ad27f91d18526f143f6ba1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L1063-L1073) and the doc for `def as(alias: String): Column = name(alias)` is [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8f24a7f54d9abd0cb7ad27f91d18526f143f6ba1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L1075-L1089). As you can see in the scaladoc of `alias` says

> Gives the column an alias. Same as `as`.

So, both methods do the same.

About how `'value` work? You can have a good explanation in the post [What are some example use cases for symbol literals in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780287/what-are-some-example-use-cases-for-symbol-literals-in-scala). These feature is deprecated as you can see here https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-dropped-features.html#symbol-literals